# How can I apply gravity on multiple CraftyJS components?

Tags: javascript, craftyjs

I have three components, `Ground`, `Block`, and `Player`. I want player to stop falling when coming in contact with both `Ground` and `Block` entities. I have tried `this.gravity("Ground, Block");` and `this.gravity("Ground", "Block");` but the former disables gravity on both components and the latter enables gravity for the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

Use a single component that is added to any that need this functionality.  So you could call `this.gravity("Platform")`, and then require it for any components that can be stood upon:

```
Crafty.c("Ground", {
   required: "Platform",
   init: function(){
     // etc   
   }, 
});
```

You don't even need to provide a specific definition for "Platform", since in this case it's just used as a marker component.

An advantage of this approach is that as we create new types of things the player can stand on, we don't have to extend a list in the player object -- we just add the "Platform" component to them as well.